# Fatal error: Class 'RccgPraiseCentre\User\PDO' not found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Want to retrieve information from a table in my database, base on the argument supplied to the function as well as the field name and its giving this error "**Fatal error**:  Class 'RccgPraiseCentre\User\PDO' not found in **C:\xampp\htdocs\RCCG\app\RccgPraiseCentre\User\HomeMenu.php** on line **22**
"
**Here is the function inside a class.  HomeMenu.php file**

```
            <?php
            namespace RccgPraiseCentre\User; 


            class HomeMenu{
                public  $errorArray = array();

                private $db; 

                function __construct($db)
                {
                    $this -> db = $db;
                }



            //display all slider base on id  
            public function bannerSlider($id){
                $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  slider_tbl WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
                $query->execute(array($id));
                if($query->rowCount()>0){
                $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
                }else{
                    echo '<h2 style="color:white;">RCCG Praise Centre Area Headquater</h2>';
                }}
```

**The line 22 is this piece of code  $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);**

Here is the page i am calling the function to

```
    <?php
    include_once"includeFiles/dbconfig.php";

    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
    use RccgPraiseCentre\User\HomeMenu as HomeMenu;


    $object = new HomeMenu($db);
    echo $object->bannerSlider('1')['header_title'];

    ?>
```

the "header_title" is a field name in my table, am trying to get info from the field... i want to get information from table using something like this  echo $object->bannerSlider('1')['header_title']; ,  echo $object->bannerSlider('1')['header_body']; ,  echo $object->bannerSlider('1')['header_link']; etc. I appreciate your effort in helping me solve this problem.

```
    <?php

    $DB_host = "localhost";
    $DB_user = "root";
    $DB_pass = "";
    $DB_name = "rccgpraisecentre";

    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have defined your file in a namespace, you need to either import classes with `use` or prefix with `\` to indicate you want a class from the root namespace instead of the current namespace.

The issue is this constant: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` which would be resolved with `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or resolved by adding `use PDO;` underneath the namespace declaration.